# Is linearity sufficient to guarantee probabilities are invariant under change of reference frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, unitarity

In his *Symmetry Principles in Quantum Physics*, Fonda seems to write (in a footnote at the bottom of page 13) that if a bijection $T$ on a vector space is linear or antilinear, then for any $\phi,\psi$ we have
$$|(T\psi,T\phi)|^2 = |(\psi,\phi)|^2.$$
Obviously (I think) this is not true, since the given criterion holds only for unitary (or antiunitary) operators as far as I know. Am I missing something?

Please see the attached in case you are worried I am misinterpreting Fonda. The relevant discussion begins with the first full paragraph on page 12.

[image]

Comment: As you've phrased the statement, it is clearly wrong. Take e.g. $T=a\mathbb I$ with $a>0$. But it is hard for me to understand what the author wants to say in the footnote (English is not my native language...)

Comment: You wield the language well nevertheless! At any rate, I think I understand them now. Linearity is not enough, but since $T$ also takes unit rays into unit rays (and since preservation of the norm is equivalent to unitarity) we obtain the desired result. @TobiasFünke

Comment: You could transform your comment into an answer.